# Is the complexity of Pollard rho for discrete logartihm really the modulus?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, pollard-rho, prime-field

so I'm reading everywhere that the Pollard Rho for Dlog's complexity of $g^a \pmod{n}$ is $\mathcal O(\sqrt{n})$.

Shouldn't it be $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{q})$ with $q$ the order of $g$?

Comment: Note that of course $\mathcal O(\sqrt q)\subseteq\mathcal O(\sqrt n)$ since $q\leq n$, hence claiming the algorithm to be in $\mathcal O(\sqrt n)$ is not *wrong*, it is just not a tight bound. In the typical context of "safe primes", Geoffroy Couteau's answer applies and we even have $\mathcal O(\sqrt q)=\mathcal O(\sqrt n)$.

Comment: well, even $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{q}) = \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$ for what is worth. I don't understand why we keep using these asymptotic notations in cryptography... they convey no practical meaning.

Comment: I do not agree; although benchmarks convey more "practical meanings", they are heavily dependent of the particular computer that was used. In particular for DLOG attacks on finite fields, asymptotic complexities (written with the L() function for subexponential complexities) translate quite accurately to efficiency improvements. Knowing that the complexity of the best attack on some DLOG on a group is $O(\sqrt{q})$ suggests taking q twice bigger (in bit-length) than your desired security parameter, and it gives you a quite good estimation on the size of the modulus.

Comment: the fact that some cryptosystem could be broken if the algorithm would work in $\sqrt{q}$ operations instead of $\sqrt{n}$ operations shows how important some distinctions are no?

(I guess from this is especially important from the point of view of the attacker)

Comment: Have you seen anyone still use $n$ for [the modulus from which one takes the multiplicative group] when they wrote $\hspace{.02 in}O\hspace{-0.04 in}\left(\hspace{-0.04 in}\sqrt{n}\hspace{-0.02 in}\right)\hspace{.02 in}$? $\;$

Comment: yeah from the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard's_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms check the complexity section

Comment: That section doesn't say n is the modulus. ​ ​

Comment: woops, you are completely right. I think I just mixed together -_- several sources I read

Answer (score 4):

The complexity of Pollard-Rho is indeed $O(\sqrt{\text{ord}(g)})$, but even though $n$ refers to the modulus, their statement might be correct depending of the context. If the modulus considered in your situation is a "classical" modulus in crypto (e.g. $n = (2q+1)^k$ for a prime $q$ and a small $k$, etc), as the modulus will be in general chosen so that ord$(g)$ is big, $n = t\cdot \text{ord}(g)$ for a small constant $t$ so $O(\sqrt{\text{ord}(g)}) = O(\sqrt{n})$.

Answer (score 2):

It should be $\;\; O\Big(\hspace{-0.07 in}\sqrt{\text{order of g}}\hspace{-0.02 in}\Big) \:$ group exponentiations $\;\;$ .

When $q$ is the order of $g$, that will be $\;\; O\hspace{-0.04 in}\left(\hspace{-0.04 in}\sqrt{q}\hspace{-0.02 in}\right) \:$ group exponentiations $\;\;$ .

When $n$ is the order of $g$, that will be $\;\; O\hspace{-0.04 in}\left(\hspace{-0.04 in}\sqrt{n}\hspace{-0.02 in}\right) \:$ group exponentiations $\;\;$ .

Were they still using $n$ for [the modulus from which one

takes the multiplicative group] when they wrote $\hspace{.02 in}O\hspace{-0.04 in}\left(\hspace{-0.04 in}\sqrt{n}\hspace{-0.02 in}\right)\hspace{.02 in}$?

Comment: yes, from the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard's_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms

Comment: I just made the question more precise. ​ ​